# How to describe myself at a very young age(say 5), is "little me" ok

Tags: word-request

I am wondering how to denote myself at very young age. For example, in the following sentence :If I could live over again, I would tell the "little me" to put maximum effort into study.
Is "little me" OK here or there can be better expression?

Comment: Completely off topic, but it's more beneficial for five-year-olds to play and experiment in their environment than "studying hard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all fine:

"*I would tell...*

- *little me*
- *young me*
- *5-year-old me*
- *my little self*
- *my young self*
- *my 5-year-old self*

*...to put maximum effort into study.*"

The versions with "me" are more casual, and the ones with "my...self" are neutral or formal.

Comment: Thoes expresions are so helpful, I really appreiciate your help my friends!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It is your choice of expression.  There is no fixed or standard expression to use, and "little me" makes sense in context.

Alternatively "myself" would mean almost the same, in context.

Answer (score 0):

“Little me” or “little old me” is an idiomatic way of mocking another’s concerns about you or your actions.  “You don’t think little me would be capable of eating all that ice-cream that doesn’t belong to me, do you?”

Better to say “young me”, “five-year-old me”, or “my younger self”.

Comment: :I got it. Thank for extending the meaning of "little me " and the example you gave. It help for me to understand why other expressions are better way to say. Thank you again, my friend!!